# configuring opencv for use with python 3.3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, configuration, installation

I am compiling `opencv 2.0` from source, and I would like to use it with `python 3`, in particular `python 3.3.2` (but I could use anything above that). I am compiling as a cluster user, so I have no administrative rights. When installation is complete (`cmake`, `make`, `make install`), I cannot find any python directory in the installation dir. After running `cmake` I get

```
Python 2:
  Interpreter:         /usr/bin/python2 (ver 2.6.6)

Python 3:
  Interpreter:         /some/other/folder/python3 (ver 3.3.2)

Python (for build):    /usr/bin/python2
```

Can anybody clarify how to correctly build modules for python 3 (any version of python 3)?

Comment: Use pip install

Comment: Do you absolutely have to build it from source ?  Otherwise, if you are using Windows, you could just grab the opencv package that corresponds to your python version (from 3.4 to 3.6 only)  from this page: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv
Then install it with pip install "name of package"

Comment: I am on linux cluster.

Comment: Why do you use OpenCV 2.0 but not a newer version, i.e. 3.1 or 3.2?

Comment: @QuangHoang I thought that 2.0 was the latest stable release

Comment: 2.0 is deprecated, 2.4.12 is the latest 2.x version. 3.2 is the latest stable version. (Much like python 2.7 and python 3.6). Also, it would be useful if you specify your OS.